# How to set up this scope with association in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, scope, associations

I'm having trouble writing and testing a scope involving a couple of joins and associations.  I'll try to keep my explanation brief but as thorough as possible.

I have the following associations:

`ExpertTopic > Topic > Articles > Posts`

and the following code:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :order => "position", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :posts, :through => :articles

  has_many :expert_topic, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :experts, :through => :expert_topic
end
```

And:

```
class ExpertTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic, :inverse_of => :expert_topic
  belongs_to :expert, :inverse_of => :expert_topic

  scope :live, joins(:topic => {:articles => :post})
    .where("topics.article_count > ? AND posts.live = ?", 0, true)
end
```

**With the `live` scope in `ExpertTopic`, I'm trying to narrow down to those experts associated with topics with all live posts in them (through articles).**

In the Rails console `ExpertTopic.live.to_sql` is:

```
"SELECT `experts_topics`.* FROM `experts_topics` INNER JOIN 
`topics` ON `topics`.`id` = `experts_topics`.`topic_id` INNER JOIN
`articles` ON `articles`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`id` INNER JOIN
`posts` ON `posts`.`id` = `articles`.`post_id` WHERE
(topics.article_count > 0 AND posts.live = 1)"
```

I'm testing my scope with the following code in `expert_topic_spec.rb`:

```
describe ExpertTopic do
  before do
    @post1 = FactoryGirl.create(:pending_post)
    @post2 = FactoryGirl.create(:live_post)
    @post3 = FactoryGirl.create(:pending_post)
    @post4 = FactoryGirl.create(:live_post)
    @non_live_topic = FactoryGirl.create(:topic_with_posts, :posts => [@post1, @post2, @post3])
    @live_topic = FactoryGirl.create(:topic_with_posts, :posts => [@post2, @post4])
    FactoryGirl.create(:expert_topic, topic_id: @non_live_topic.id)
    FactoryGirl.create(:expert_topic, topic_id: @live_topic.id)
  end

  it 'finds and returns only expert with live topic' do
    ExpertTopic.all.count.should == 2
    ExpertTopic.live.uniq.count.should == 1
  end
end
```

**The logic is that since `@non_live_topic` contains at least one post that's not live it is not considered live and hence shouldn't be returned by a call to `ExpertTopic.live`.  However, the last assertion fails because `ExpertTopic.live.uniq.count` returns `2` instead of `1`.**

I don't know if my scope is written incorrectly or if it's my test, and I'd really appreciate someone's help in debugging!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> The logic is that since @non_live_topic contains at least one post that's not live it is not considered live

This is not correct.  The `live` scope doesn't exclude `ExpertTopic`s that are associated with a non-live post.  It simply includes `ExpertTopic`s that are associated with one or more live posts. This means that if both a live and non-live post are associated, it will be included.

To change the scope to the logic you expect you'll need to use an exclusion clause, for example:

```
scope :live, lambda {
    non_live_sql = joins(:topic => {:articles => :post})
      .where("topics.article_count > ? AND posts.live = ?", 0, false)
      .select('expert_topics.id').to_sql
    joins(:topic).where("topics.article_count > ? AND expert_topics.id NOT IN (#{non_live_sql})", 0)
}
```

There are other ways in SQL to exclude items, but this is probably the simplest to build in rails without involving a DSL such as Squeel or writing out a large query by hand.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I thought there might be a flaw in my logic but I needed someone smarter than me to point out what it was.  Thanks so much!  I'd give you two up votes if I could for providing such a helpful answer!